# prove that this operator integral is not compact

Tags: real-analysis, integration, general-topology, functional-analysis, analysis

how to show that the operator $T(t)$ defined on $\mathbb{X}= \left\{ u \in \mathbf{C}\left(\overline{\mathbb{R}}\right): \lim\limits_{ x \rightarrow \pm \infty} u(x) = 0\right\}$ endowed with the norm $$\|u\|_{\infty} = \sup_{-\infty <x<+\infty} |u(x)|$$ by :

$T(t)f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi t}} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{-\frac{|x-y|^{2}}{4t}}f(y) \, dy$.

is not compact ?

Comment: I think you are missing a square in the exponential of the heat kernel

Comment: yes sir,  thank you

Comment: What is the norm on $\mathbb{X}$?

Comment: $$\|u\|_{\infty} = \sup_{-\infty <x<+\infty} |u(x)|$$

Answer (score 0):

**Sketch:** Observe
\begin{align}
T(t)f(x) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int d\xi\ e^{i\xi x} e^{-4\xi^2 t}\hat f(\xi).
\end{align}
Choose $f_n(x)$ such that $\hat f_n(\xi) = \chi_{[n, n+1]}(\xi)e^{4\xi^2 t}$. It's clear that $f_n \in \mathbb{X}$ since $\hat f_n$ in $L^1$ and
\begin{align}
|f_n(x)| \leq \frac{1}{2\pi} \int^{n+1}_n d\xi\  = \frac{1}{2\pi}.
\end{align}
However, we see that
\begin{align}
T(t)f_n(x) =&\ \frac{1}{2\pi}\int^{n+1}_n d\xi\ e^{ix\xi}  = \frac{e^{i(n+1)x}-e^{inx}}{2\pi ix} = e^{i(n+\frac{1}{2})x}\frac{\sin(\frac{x}{2})}{\pi x}\\
 =&\ \cos((n+\frac{1}{2})x)\frac{\sin(\frac{x}{2})}{\pi x}+i\sin((n+\frac{1}{2})x)\frac{\sin(\frac{x}{2})}{\pi x}
\end{align}
which means
\begin{align}
T(t)f_n(x)-T(t)f_m(x) =&\ (e^{i(n+\frac{1}{2})x}-e^{i(m+\frac{1}{2})x})\frac{\sin(\frac{x}{2})}{\pi x}.
\end{align}
It remains to show that $\|T(t)f_n(x)-T(t)f_m(x)\|_\infty>C$ for all $n, m$ for some constant $C$ independent of $n, m$.